# How to check for Exception property with PHPunit

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I have the following exception:

```
<?php
namespace App\Exception;

class LimitReachedException extends \Exception
{
    private ?\DateTime $resumeAt;

    ...getter/setter..
}
```

My PHPUnit check for this exception like this:

```
$this->expectException(LimitReachedException::class);
```

How can I check that a certain value is stored in the `$resumeAt` property as well?

Comment: Is this Laravel? What errors are you getting back? Is it not working or not working as expected? Did you try anything else? What is throwing the exception and what does your test looks like?

Comment: No this is Symfony, but that's not relevant. My code is working correctly(catching the exception that's thrown). I just want to know how to also test for certain properties to be set on that exception.

Comment: Everything is relevant, I do not know Symfony, but in Laravel, you simply throw the exception and the test will catch it, but you could be using a Laravel Handler so not return the exception, so the test would not catch it... everything is relevant...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though PHPUnit has a `expectExceptionObject` method that allows passing an exception instance, that is just a shortcut to `expectExceptionMessage`, `expectException` and `expectExceptionCode`.

One way to achieve your assertion as of now (current version of PHPUnit being 9.5.27) is to instead of using PHPUnit's methods of expecting that exception is to catch it yourself and then assert the different properties:

```php
function testException () {
    $expectedException = null;
    try {
        $foo->doSomething();
    } catch (LimitReachedException $e) {
        $expectedException = $e;
    }

    // Put your assertions outside of the `catch` block, otherwise
    // your test won't fail when the exception isn't thrown
    // (it will turn risky instead because there are no assertions)
    $this->assertInstanceOf(LimitReachedException::class, $expectedException);
    $this->assertSame('myExceptionProperty', $expectedException->getProperty());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I put expectException before the issued test:

```
public function test_user_can_not_update_profile ()
{
    $user = User::factory()->create();

    $this->expectException(\PDOException::class);
    $this->expectException(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException::class);
    $profile = Profile::create([
        'website' => 'http://test.si'
    ]);

    $this->assertNull($user->fresh()->profile);
}
```